# eventListener is not running after the page is updated

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, mouseover

I have written this code to get the squares of a grid to change their background color to black upon a mouseover event. It works when the page initially loads, but if I create a new grid the mouseover event no longer works.

I updated the original post with a snippet. Sorry I didn't do that from the beginning.

```js
    let number = 16;
    makeGrid(number);

    function makeGrid(number) {
        for (let i=0; i < number; i++) {
            for (let j=0; j < number; j++) {
                const rows = document.createElement('div');
                const container = document.getElementById('container')
                rows.setAttribute('class', 'rows');
                container.appendChild(rows);
            }    
        } 
        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${number}, 1fr)`;
        container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${number}, 1fr)`;
    }


    //create new grid with on button
    let newGrid = document.getElementById('newGrid');
    newGrid.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let number = prompt('Enter a number');
        let container = document.getElementById('container');
        container.textContent = '';
        makeGrid(number);
    })

    //change background color to black
    let changeClass = document.querySelectorAll('.rows');
    changeClass.forEach((item) => { 
    item.addEventListener('mouseover', e => { 
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
     })
})
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(5, 51, 5) ;
}

#container { 
            
            margin: auto;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            display: grid;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: thin;
            border-color: lightslategray;
            background-color: white;
           }

.rows{ 
        
            
    }

.black { background-color: black;

    }

#header {
            text-align: center;
    }  

#button {
            text-align: center;
    }

#footer {
            text-align: center;
    }

#newGrid {
            background-color: lightgray;
            color: darkcyan;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 12px 28px;
            border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id='header'>Etch-a-Sketch</h1>
    <br>
   <div id='button'>
    <button id='newGrid' class='button'>New Grid</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id='container'></div>
    <br>
    <footer id='footer'>Made by: Joe Maniaci</footer>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please create a minimal example using the builtin editor and add the corresponding html?

Comment: Probably, a guess because it's not a full example, but at the time the code runs, the elements don't exist yet. You should attach the listener to the document or a parent container instead of the individual .rows elements, so that as new ones are created, they still qualify for the event.

Comment: I updated the original post to include a snippet. Sorry for the incomplete post to begin with. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

When you query the DOM with `document.querySelectorAll('.rows')` and add the event listeners, there is only one "grid" in the DOM at that time. When a "grid" is subsequently added to the DOM, as triggered by the user's click event, you must instantiate event listeners on the newly added DOM nodes too.

A way to avoid this problem and a better approach overall in your situation is to use delegated event listeners. For example:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseover', e=>{
  if(e.target.matches(‘.myClickableItemClass’){
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  }
}
```

Learn more about event delegation here: https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/part-4-what-is-event-delegation-in-javascript-f5c8c0de2983